# Image blending dependent on image column

Tags: image-processing

I have two images:

[image]
[image]

I can blend them:

```
img1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PJxM.png"];
img2 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/blxtM.png"];
x = 0.5;
Blend[{img1, img2}, x]
```

Output:

[image]

Now how do I do the blending in such a way that "x" varies with image column? I want to get an image that is red on the left side, then transitions smoothly in the middle and is yellow on the right side

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is:

```
img3 = ImageMultiply[img1, 
   LinearGradientImage[{White, Black}, ImageDimensions[img1]]];
img4 = ImageMultiply[img2, 
   LinearGradientImage[{Black, White}, ImageDimensions[img1]]];
ImageAdd[img4, img3]
```

[image]

Comment: That looks good. Now I just need a way to make it so that transition is more focused in the middle. Using image that is 1/3 black, 1/3gradient and 1/3 white instead of gradient should do it. Do you know how to accomplish this?

Comment: @AdamSikora I suggest you fiddle with the gradient lists yourself until you get what you want. You could do for instance: `LinearGradientImage[{Red, White, Black}, ImageDimensions[img1]` and `LinearGradientImage[{Black, White, Yellow}, ImageDimensions[img1]`, and even make lists of different lengths.

Comment: Or make varying lists with the colors `White,Gray,Black`.

Comment: `{White, White, White, Gray, Black, Black, Black}` did the trick perfectly. Thanks Feyre

Answer (score 4):

This is basically a custom version of `Blend` that takes a function, which can depend on x and y, that should return the fraction:

```
blend[{i1_, i2_}, f_] := ImageAdd[
  ImageApplyIndexed[adjust[f], i1],
  ImageApplyIndexed[adjust[1 - f[##] &], i2]
  ]

adjust[frac_][{r_, g_, b_, a___}, {y_, x_}] := Append[frac[x, y] {r, g, b}, a]
```

Here is how we can use it:

```
{w, h} = ImageDimensions[img1];    
blend[{img1, img2}, #/w &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]